# kendo ui web grid sorting error while editing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have gird with inline edit and editable column displayed as drop-down list. When I select any item and then do sort, I get [object Object] as the value for the cell. As of now, I have written code to remove it as below.

```
dataBound: function(e) {
               if(e.sender != null) {
                    var container = e.sender;
                    var rows = container.tbody[0].childNodes;
                    $.each(rows, function (i, val) {
                        var cols = rows[i].childNodes;
                        $.each(cols, function (k, value) {
                            if(cols[k].innerText == "[object Object]")
                                cols[k].innerText = "";
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
```

Does somebody have better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by calling grid header on click event and within it I check if that column is sortable and if it is, then call cancelChanges() method of grid.

```
$(function () {
            var gr = $('#grid').data().kendoGrid;
            gr.thead.on('click', function (e) {
                if((e.target && e.target.href) || (e.target.cellIndex && gr.columns[e.target.cellIndex].sortable))
                    gr.cancelChanges();
            });
        });
```

Also, add sortable property to fields in grid like below even sortable=true is default.

```
columns: [
                            "ProductName",
                            { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", sortable:true, format: "{0:c}", width: "100px" },
                            { field: "UnitsInStock", title:"Units In Stock", sortable:true, width: "100px" },
                            { field: "Discontinued", sortable:false, width: "100px" },
                            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", sortable:false, width: "172px" }]
```